# File path in different activity

Tags: java, android

in activity NumberAndText I'm creating a file that has a path:

```
String filePath = NumberAndText.this.getFilesDir().getPath().toString() + "/contact.txt";
```

Then i MainActivity I want to access this file even when NumberAndText activity is dead. How can I do it?

Comment: getFilesDir().getPath().toString() + "/contact.txt";

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `MainActivity` likely is an Activity, it will extend [Context](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html) which implements the function [getFilesDir()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getFilesDir()). So simply call `getFilesDir()` from `MainActivity` like:

```
String filePath = getFilesDir().getPath().toString() + "/contact.txt";
```

Comment: Thanks it works :) In other version I need to open it in a Fragment. What about it? EDIT: I see that getContext() worked :)

Comment: @Endoplasma Then you can simply get the `Activity` using `getActivity()` and then get the path in the same way as before. Oh and please accept the answer if it worked for you.